# How to select a specific percentage of lines?

Tags: bash, awk

Goodmorning !

I have a file.csv with 140 lines and 26 columns. I need to sort the lines in  according the values in column 23. This is an exemple :

```
Controller1,NA,ASHEBORO,ASH,B,,3674,4572,1814,3674,4572,1814,1859,#NAME?,0,124.45%,49.39%,19%,1,,"Big Risk, No Spare disk",45.04%,4.35%,12.63%,160,464,,,,,,0,1,1,1,0,410,65%,1.1,1.1,1.3,0.65,0.65,0.75,0.04,0.1,,,,,,,,,
Controller2,EU,FR,URG,D,,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,#NAME?,0,#DIV/0!,#DIV/0!,#DIV/0!,1,,#N/A,0.00%,0.00%,#DIV/0!,NO STATS,-1088,,,,,,#N/A,#N/A,#N/A,#N/A,0,#N/A,65%,1.1,1.1,1.3,0.65,0.65,0.75,0.04,0.1,,,,,,,,,
Controller3,EU,FR,URG,D,,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,#NAME?,0,#DIV/0!,#DIV/0!,#DIV/0!,1,,#N/A,0.00%,0.00%,#DIV/0!,NO STATS,-2159,,,,,,#N/A,#N/A,#N/A,#N/A,0,#N/A,65%,1.1,1.1,1.3,0.65,0.65,0.75,0.04,0.1,,,,,,,,,
Controller4,NA,STARR,STA,D,,4430,6440,3736,4430,6440,3736,693,#NAME?,0,145.38%,84.35%,18%,1,,No more Data disk,65.17%,19.18%,-2.18%,849,-96,,,,,,0,2,1,2,2,547,65%,1.1,1.1,1.3,0.65,0.65,0.75,0.04,0.1,,,,,,,,,
```

To sort the lines according the values of the column 23, I do this :

```
awk -F "%*," '$23 > 4' myfikle.csv
```

The result :

```
Controller1,NA,ASHEBORO,ASH,B,,3674,4572,1814,3674,4572,1814,1859,#NAME?,0,124.45%,49.39%,19%,1,,"Big Risk, No Spare disk",45.04%,4.35%,12.63%,160,464,,,,,,0,1,1,1,0,410,65%,1.1,1.1,1.3,0.65,0.65,0.75,0.04,0.1,,,,,,,,,
Controller4,NA,STARR,STA,D,,4430,6440,3736,4430,6440,3736,693,#NAME?,0,145.38%,84.35%,18%,1,,No more Data disk,65.17%,19.18%,-2.18%,849,-96,,,,,,0,2,1,2,2,547,65%,1.1,1.1,1.3,0.65,0.65,0.75,0.04,0.1,,,,,,,,,
```

In my example, I use the value of 4% in column 23, the goal being to retrieve all the rows with their value in % which increases significantly in column 23. The problem is that I can't base myself on the 4% value because it is only representative of the current table. So I have to find another way to retrieve the rows that have a high value in column 23.

I have to sort the Controllers in descending order according to the percentage in column 23, I prefer to process the first 10% of the sorted lines to make sure I have the controllers with a large percentage.

The goal is to be able to vary the percentage according to the number of lines in the table.

Do you have any tips for that ?

Thanks ! :)

Comment: Please, post some sample data with related expected output along with some work done.

Comment: @Ezzmazz, I second to James sir here, please do mention samples of input and expected output in code tags. Also do mention your efforts which you have put in order to solve your own problem.

Comment: @JamesBrown  Excuse me ! I change that ! :)

Comment: Can't you have come up with a [mcve] that has, say, 5 columns sorted on column 4 instead of us having to wade through an example with 50 columns (or however many that is) sorted by the 23rd to try to help you? You might get more people willing to help if you do that. `$23 > 4'` doesn't `sort the lines according the values of the column 23` btw - it selects the lines with a value greater than 4 in column 23.

Answer (score 1):

I could have sworn that this question was a duplicate, but so far I couldn't find a similar question.

Whether your file is sorted or not does not really matter. From any file you can extract the `NUMBER` first lines with `head -n NUMBER`. There is no built-in way to specify the number percentually, but you can compute that `PERCENT`% of your file's lines are `NUMBER` lines.

```
percentualHead() {
  percent="$1"
  file="$2"
  linesTotal="$(wc -l < "$file")"
  (( lines = linesTotal * percent / 100  ))
  head -n "$lines" "$file"
}
```

or shorter but less readable

```
percentualHead() {
  head -n "$(( "$(wc -l < "$2")" * "$1" / 100  ))" "$2"
}
```

Calling `percentualHead 10 yourFile` will print the first 10% of lines from `yourFile` to stdout.

Note that `percentualHead` only works with files because the file has to be read twice. It does not work with FIFOs, `<()`, or pipes.

Comment: Thanks you for your answer !

So, can I use it like this : 

percentualHead 10 Myfile.csv > 10%ofmyfile.csv ?

and What is " stdout " ?

Comment: @Ezzmazz Yes, you can use it like this after your defined the function as shown in this answer. Note that `Myfile.csv` has to be sorted to achieve what you asked for. `stdout` is the standard output stream which usually is printed on the terminal. With `> file` you direct that output to a file.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use standard tools, you'll need to read the file twice.  But if you're content to use perl, you can simply do:

```
perl -e 'my @sorted = sort <>; print @sorted[0..$#sorted * .10]' input-file
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one for GNU awk to get the top *p*% from the file but they are outputed in the order of appearance:

```
$ awk -F, -v p=0.5 '               # 50 % of top $23 records
NR==FNR {                          # first run
    a[NR]=$23                      # hash precentages to a, NR as key
    next
}
FNR==1 {                           # second run, at beginning
    n=asorti(a,a,"@val_num_desc")  # sort percentages to descending order
    for(i=1;i<=n*p;i++)            # get only the top p %
        b[a[i]]                    # hash their NRs to b
}
(FNR in b)                         # top p % BUT not in order
' file file | cut -d, -f 23        # file processed twice, cut 23rd for demo
45.04%
19.18%
```

Commenting this in a bit.